# How to ingnore current directory when I use function fs::dir_ls?

Tags: r, path, fs

I want to get list of files paths. my current directory in R is: `/home/R/user1/proj/dev/"`. I want to get paths of files from directory `/home/R/user2/proj/dev/data"`. I use function fs::dir_ls():

```
file_paths <- fs::dir_ls(
    path = file.path("~/R/user2/proj/dev/data"),
    globe = "*.csv",
    type = "file"
)
```

But file_paths[1] gives me this:

```
/home/R/user1/proj/dev/R/user2/proj/dev/data/file1.csv
```

instead of:

```
/home/R/user2/proj/dev/data/file1.csv
```

How to fix it and ignore current directory path?

Comment: Maybe use `/home/R/user2/proj/dev/data` instead of `~/R/user2/proj/dev/data`

Comment: Also test what you will get from `setwd("~"); getwd()`

Comment: @GKi ```setwd("~"); getwd()``` gives me ```/home/user1```. and those files are in ```/home/user2```

Comment: Then use either the full path or `~/../R/user2/proj/dev/data` could also work as `~` is in your case not `/home/R/` what you have expected.